# Cookies are not Set in Header Request file

Tags: php, cookies

Currently I wanted to Access the Url Which require A cookie.Without Cookie It redirect to other Url. I try to Set Cookie in request header but only getting the Cookies in response header. Don't know Why it Happen.

this is Response Header:

```
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0,   pre-check=0
    Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8 Date Mon, 26 Sep 2016 11:52:59 GMT    Expires 
    Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
    Location    
    quotev3.php?sub=compare
    Pragma  
    no-cache
    Server  
    nginx
    Set-Cookie  
    PHPSESSID=e2dnbfjvhi29e7qnkm0jbnekc4; path=/
    country=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0
    X-Firefox-Spdy  
    h2
```

Request Header

```
   Accept   
*/*
Accept-Encoding 
gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language 
en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection  
keep-alive
Content-Length  
119
Content-Type    
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host    
www.parcelmonkey.co.uk
Origin  
null
User-Agent  
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0
```

I set  a Cookie in header File Like that.

```
    $cookie=$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'];
ob_start();
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Request-With');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Cookie:'.$cookie);
```

Any Solution Will be very Appriciated.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the key of the cookie, not just it's value.

Also, the command is `Set-Cookie` and not `Cookie`.

Use the `setcookie` function, or `header` like this:

```
setcookie('PHPSESSID', $cookie);
```

or

```
header("Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID={$cookie};");
```